# Vertical ScrollBar does not appear at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

my vertical scrollbar never appears at run time.

this is my markup:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"  >
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" AcceptsTab="True" 
    Height="200"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtRecord" 
         Margin="0,3,0,0" 
         AcceptsReturn="True"  
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></TextBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

what it looks like when i run it:

[image]

only thing about it all is that this textbox is inside a usercontrol...

Comment: Height of the textbox (content of ScrollViewer ) should be bigger than ScrollViewer height to appear the  vertical scrollbar. change textbox height .

Comment: or remove `Height="200"`.

Comment: But my text height needs to be 200 though and when input text goes beyond the height of 200 the scroll bar still does not appear

Comment: Your Xaml works .(when txtRecord.Text is big)

Comment: @MitraM sorry for the delay. what do you mean when 'big'? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not to use ScrollViewer as TextBox will show vertical scrollbar. How about changing Markup as follows:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0"  
         IsReadOnly="True" AcceptsTab="True" 
         Height="200"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Name="txtRecord" 
         Margin="0,3,0,0" 
         AcceptsReturn="True"  
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"></TextBox>
```

There may be a possibility for the text box to be wide so that the right side of the textbox is hidden somehow within ScrollViewer.

Comment: Hi thanks yes. Originally did that and it did not work

Comment: How about trying ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility attached property? Did you try it?

Comment: sorry for the delay in response.  this did not work either.